# history.go(-1) going back doesnt work in Chrome

Tags: javascript

`href="#" onclick="closeOrCancel()` and `history.go(-1)` in that js method doesnt work in Chrome (neither `history.back()`)

It works with `href="javascript:closeOrCancel()"` , but Opera doesn't allow `href="javascript:...`

How to make history go back using onclick= "myFunction()" ?

Edit: `closeOrCancel()` returns false

Comment: What is `closeOrCancel()`? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: just my js function, where history.go(-1)  .. trying to go back 1 page  with onclick method

Comment: It's not nice to delete questions after answers have already been given :( (Not related to this question, but you'll know what I'm talking about)

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen: It's better to delete than to mark -1. My question was not correctly provided and your answer did not make sense. That's why I deleted it. Apologies

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Adding a `return false;` to the `onclick` code seems to be enough:

```
<a href="#" onclick="closeOrCancel(); return false;">Go Back</a>
```

Comment: or simpler: `onclick="return closeOrCancel()"` since it was stated that the function returned false

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong about two things here:

- Opera **allows** href="javascript:...
- history.go(-1) **works** in Chrome.

Please provide source for your script, since the problem is clearly in it and not the browsers.

Just put this in a html file and open it to see for yourself:

```
<script>
function goback() {
    history.go(-1);
}
</script>
<a href="javascript:goback()">goback</a>
<a href="#ttttt">tt</a>
```

First click the "tt" link, then "goback". See the hash change. It works fine, although I'd personally recommend against using javascript in href's.

Comment: Difficult to say what was up then. Most likely your script did something else which kind of screwed it up, since the above code works for me :)

Answer (score -2):

I used `history.go(-2);` to go back to step 1 in chrome.

Comment: This is not good practice as it will generate an undesired outcome in other browsers (take two steps back). onclick="history.go(-1); return false;" will work just fine.